# Refresh menu scene after data change (Corona SDK)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have just implemented adbuddiz reward video in my app and it works as expected but I have a slight challenge.

After watching the video, it triggers the "didComplete" event for adbuddiz where it adds the needed value into a json file.

The challenge now is the value does not automatically reflect on the screen except I go out of the scene and go back before the new value shows.

Is there a way to refresh the screen so the new value appears immediately?

**Note: This all happens on a button click**

```
local savecount = Lib.getSaveValue("savecount")

    -- Events (rewarded video)
local function listenerRewardedVideo( event ) 
    if event.value == "didFetch" then
        print( "didFetch" )
    end
    if event.value == "didComplete" then
        print( "didComplete" )
        -- Reward user here
        print ("savecount")
        savecount = savecount + 1
        Lib.setSaveValue("savecount", savecount, true);
        local alert = native.showAlert("Successful","Count saved successfully!", {"OK"})                            
    end
    if event.value == "didNotComplete" then
        print( "didNotComplete" )
    end
    if event.value == "didFail" then
        print( "didFail - " .. event.detail )
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "AdBuddizRewardedVideoEvent", listenerRewardedVideo )
```

This displays the value on the menu scene

```
label_saveme = display.newText({parent=uiGroup, text=savecount, x=0, y=0, font=native.systemFont, fontSize=24})
    label_saveme.xScale = 0.92
    label_saveme.x = button_buysaveme.x + 22
    label_saveme.y = button_buysaveme.y + 6
    label_saveme:setFillColor(255/255, 255/255, 255/255)
    label_saveme.alpha = 0.4
    uiGroup:insert(label_saveme)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you want to put savecount value on label_saveme?
if your local label_save me on the same file as your button click code, change the "didComplete"

```
if event.value == "didComplete" then
    print( "didComplete" )
    -- Reward user here
    print ("savecount")
    savecount = savecount + 1

    label_saveme.text = savecount

    Lib.setSaveValue("savecount", savecount, true);
    local alert = native.showAlert("Successful","Count saved successfully!", {"OK"})
end
```